# Solr: How to partial update solr documents using regular expression

Tags: json, curl, solr

Currently i am using this command:

```
curl 'localhost:8983/solr/update?commit=true' -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '[{"id":"rekhta.org/ghazals/Alama_3.8","pr":{"set":100}}]'
```

But this update happens only on the document whose id is "rekhta.org/ghazals/Alama_3.8"

How can i update documents whose id contain "ghazals" 
(e.g rekhta.org/**ghazals**/Alama_3.8). 
I am getting documents using regular expression q=id:*ghazal* but couldn't update documents using **curl** with **regular expression**

```
curl 'localhost:8983/solr/update?commit=true' -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '[{"id":"*ghazals*","pr":{"set":55}}]
```

Solr version: 4.10.3

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to retrieve all the documents and perform the update yourself. There is no way currently in Solr to perform a single update against multiple documents (aka "Update by query").

The proper way to do this would be to perform a query (using a wildcard or a regular expression match), loop through the documents and then submit an update message (either as a bulk message or single requests, depending on how many updates you're performing) that changes the content of those documents you've retrieved.